# How can I retrieve specific information from persistent session handler with PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, session, handler, persistent

I'm using PHP session handler to implement persistent session on my site.
The problem is that at some point, I need to insert the user_key into another MySQL table and I don't know how to retrieve that information from the code.

For example, the data row into my session table is:

```
active|i:1487613760;user_username|s:20:"v.lima06@hotmail.com";user_key|s:8:"a5186adc";authenticated|b:1;user_name|s:12:"victor";user_email|s:20:"v.lima06@hotmail.com";remember|b:1;
```

and I would like to know if there is a simple way to get the user_key variable.

Sorry if it was a bit confusing.

Comment: that seems a weird serialize format, how is your session handler serializing it?

Answer (score 0):

First option is to unserialize this string.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php

Second option, You can use preg_match function with the next pattern:

```
preg_match('/user_key\|s:\d+:"([a-zA-Z0-9]+)"/', $string, $match);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help 4EACH.
The problem is that I don't know how to get this specific row, once there will be a lot of sessions at the same time.

Comment: What the uniqueness information that you have on user ?

Comment: I need the user_key so that I can insert into another mysql table.
There is a method "read" to read the information with the handler...

Comment: Maybe you didn't understand my question, how you go to search the user_key ? with username? or email?

Answer (score 0):

I cant find anywhere something to handle that format of serialized string, its not something I've seen before.

However, heres a quick function to turn it into an array (it might not be overly elegant, but I've only had 1 coffee):

```
$string = 'active|i:1487613760;user_username|s:20:"v.lima06@hotmail.com";user_key|s:8:"a5186adc";authenticated|b:1;user_name|s:12:"victor";user_email|s:20:"v.lima06@hotmail.com";remember|b:1;
';

$array = deserializeSessionString($string);

echo $array['user_key'];

// deserialize a session string into an array
function deserializeSessionString($string)
{
    $output = [];
    // separate the key-value pairs and iterate
    foreach(explode(';', $string) as $p) {
        // separate the identifier with the contents
        $bits = explode('|', $p);

        // conditionally store in the correct format.
        if(isset($bits[1])) {
            $test = explode(':', $bits[1]);
            switch($test[0]) {
                // int
                case 'i':
                    $output[$bits[0]] = $test[1];
                    break;
                case 's':

                    // string
                    // ignore test[1], we dont care about it
                    $output[$bits[0]] = $test[2];
                    break;

                case 'b':
                    // boolean
                     $output[$bits[0]] = ($test[1] == 1 ? true : false);
                    break;
            }
        }

    }

    return $output;
}
```

then you should be able to access what you need with just the key:

```
echo $array['user_key'];
```

[heres an example](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/88ccecd4b5c5494474c0e25142a976f537141dae)

Comment: Thanks for your reply DevMonkey... 
It might help if i can get the session ID or some "index" to the specific row.
I dont know yet if session handler can help me with the code itself, but in the meanwhile i am setting and getting user_key on every page on the _SESSION variable...

Thank you again.